# Drone CI runner can't find gitea server

Tags: docker, networking, continuous-integration, drone.io, gitea

I am trying to run a gitea server with drone. They are currently both hosted on the same ubuntu machine and the docker containers are set up through a docker-compose.yml file.

When starting up all services I get the following error in the logs of the drone runner service:

```
time="2020-08-12T19:10:42Z" level=error msg="cannot ping the remote server" error="Post http://drone:80/rpc/v2/ping: dial tcp: lookup drone on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host"
```

Both http://gitea and http://drone point to localhost (via /etc/hosts). I sadly don't understand how or why the drone runner can not find the server. Calling "docker container inspect" on all my 4 containers shows they are all connected to the same network (drone_and_gitea_giteanet). Which is also the network I set in the DRONE_RUNNER_NETWORKS environment variable.

This is how my docker-compose.yml file looks:

```
version: "3.8"

# Create named volumes for gitea server, gitea database and drone server
volumes:
  gitea: 
  gitea-db: 
  drone: 

# Create shared network for gitea and drone
networks:
  giteanet:
    external: false
    
services:
  gitea:
    container_name: gitea
    image: gitea/gitea:1 
    #restart: always
    environment:
      - APP_NAME="Automated Student Assessment Tool"
      - USER_UID=1000
      - USER_GID=1000
      - ROOT_URL=http://gitea:3000
      - DB_TYPE=postgres
      - DB_HOST=gitea-db:5432
      - DB_NAME=gitea
      - DB_USER=gitea
      - DB_PASSWD=gitea
    networks:
      - giteanet
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "222:22"
    volumes:
      - gitea:/data
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    depends_on:
      - gitea-db

  gitea-db:
    container_name: gitea-db
    image: postgres:9.6 
    #restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=gitea
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=gitea
      - POSTGRES_DB=gitea
    networks:
      - giteanet
    volumes:
      - gitea-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    
  drone-server:
    container_name: drone-server
    image: drone/drone:1
    #restart: always
    environment:
      # General server settings
      - DRONE_SERVER_HOST=drone:80
      - DRONE_SERVER_PROTO=http
      - DRONE_RPC_SECRET=topsecret
      
      # Gitea Config
      - DRONE_GITEA_SERVER=http://gitea:3000
      - DRONE_GITEA_CLIENT_ID=<CLIENT ID>
      - DRONE_GITEA_CLIENT_SECRET=<CLIENT SECRET>
      
      # Create Admin User, name should be the same as Gitea Admin user
      - DRONE_USER_CREATE=username:AdminUser,admin:true
      
      # Drone Logs Settings
      - DRONE_LOGS_PRETTY=true
      - DRONE_LOGS_COLOR=true
    networks:
      - giteanet
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - drone:/data 
    depends_on:
      - gitea   
      
  drone-agent:
    container_name: drone-agent
    image: drone/drone-runner-docker:1 
    #restart: always
    environment:
      - DRONE_RPC_PROTO=http
      - DRONE_RPC_HOST=drone:80
      - DRONE_RPC_SECRET=topsecret
      - DRONE_RUNNER_CAPACITY=1
      - DRONE_RUNNER_NETWORKS=drone_and_gitea_giteanet
    networks:
      - giteanet
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - drone-server
```

It would help me a lot if somebody could maybe take a look at the issue and help me out! :)

Comment: The network `drone_and_gitea_giteanet` is not declared. Did you try without this option? gitea and drone containers should be able to communicate in the same network. Or try with `DRONE_RUNNER_NETWORKS=giteanet`.